# How to get the img element when we have its src property

Tags: jquery

I have a static image url (eg. "https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png"), and I want to check if there is any `img` element in my page that has that url as it's `src`. I wrote:

```
// .. loop

if($src == "https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png")
{
    $('img[src="'+ $src +'"]').css({display:'none'}); 
}

// end loop
```

It doesn't work.

Is there anyway to do that?

Comment: when you say check if its there do you mean if the image exists?

Comment: Show your code. What is your `$src` variable?

Comment: it works here: http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/vbvw1L9t/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will hide all img with the src specified:

```
$("img").each(function(){
    if( $(this).attr("src") === "https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png")
        $(this).hide();
});
```

Or you can use:

```
$("img[src*='logo11w']").hide();
```

The previous line will hide imgs that in src contains the substring *logo11w*

Comment: This is what the attribute selector does internally.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I know of to check if an image url has a valid image (On the client side) is to render the image off screen and check its dimensions.

i.e.

```
var hiddenImage = document.createElement('img');
hiddenImage.setAttribute('src', 'Some image url here');
```

Then render that somewhere not seen (give it an id and hide the id in css)
then query the image's width/height.

If you get some sizes back then you know the image url exists.

Comment: you can use onerror event for the image but seems unrelated to OP's question here

Comment: So the OP is asking how to check if an image has the url he wants, not if the url is a valid image, my mistake if that's the case